# Add multiple condition in IF statement - Python

Tags: python

Im trying to make rock, paper, scissor game by one single IF condition. Game rules are simple if player input = random number then player wins! otherwise computer wins. And im also happy if my code count score as well.

```
import random;
choices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
computer = random.choices(choices)

#player = False;
#com_score = 0;
#play_score = 0;

while True:
    player = input("rock, paper, scissor: ").capitalize();
    
    if (player == computer):
        print("tie")
        
    elif (player == "rock" or player == "paper" or player == "scissor") and computer != player:
     print("player wins and score is")
    # play_score+=1
    
    else:
        print("computer wins:",computer)
        
       
     #   print(com_score+=1)
```

Comment: welcome to SO. this doesn't seem right: you're using `.capitalize()` yet your `if` statement checks only lowercase.

Comment: Looks like you need `lower()` instead of `capitalize()`.

Answer (score 2):

use random.choice() instead because random.choices() will return a list object. Comparing a string and a list object will always result False. remove the capitalize() . Your if-else construct is correct. Your logic may be wrong.